# Ubuntu kernel modules development tools? (USB)

Tags: drivers, usb, kernel, development, tools

I'm developing a driver for a composite USB device, with vendor specific VID / PID. The device have multiple endpoints and with pnp alt_settings / descriptors. At the moment Im using code::blocks as editor, and a custom compile script running as root

```
dkms remove -m czUSB -v 0.1 --all
dkms install -m czUSB -v 0.1
rmmod czUSB
modprobe czUSB -v
```

I use dmesg together with :

```
#define DEBUG
#define DEBUG_VERBOSE
```

and I track progress using dev_err(), print_hex_dump(KERN_DEBUG,...), dev_dbg(dev,..) and so on.

What visual tools are available for developing kernel hardware driver modules for debugging, tracing, code-completion, and other help?
I'm looking for something like monodevelop.
Im using ubuntu 18.04 LTS.